# Проверка на слова из списка на Питоне для Дискорда

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Я хотел сделать своего бота на питоне для дискорда, и мне понадобилось сделать так, что бы была проверка слов из списка, что именно пишет человек, только когда я пробовал по советам из инета, у меня просто переставала работать программа, и не на что не отвечала.
Код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if "avtoriz" in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('a')
```

Только мне надо так, что бы было не просто слово, а команда с префиксом моим("!"), то есть:
Список:

```
F, Ar, gr
```

Человек:

```
!Ar
```

Пожалуйста помогите, и заранее спасибо)

Comment: Привет, тебе нужно чтобы человек обязательно перед словами "F, Ar, gr" ставил "!", или нет?

Comment: Нуу.... просто иногда если человек скажет его, таким образом он пинганёт так сказать бота, который напишет что то

Comment: Если тебе надо проверить, имеет ли сообщение префикс, используй **if message.content.startswith("!")**